# android cordova Could not open camera with <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">

Tags: android, cordova, camera

i can't use capture="camera"   with cordova app in android device, although if i open the application from browser it work fine, I am sure the cordova app have all permissions to open camera

[image: image when use cordova app]

[image: image when use browser]

image when use cordova app:

image when use browser work fine: